# Error al eliminar archivo .log

Tags: python, logger

Hola a todos estoy intentando eliminar un archivo *.log* desde python en windows, pero al hacerlo me genera el siguiente error: `PermissionError: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso: 'ot.log'` el código que estoy ejecutando es el siguiente

```
from loguru import logger
import os

logger.add("ot.log")
logger.success("Successfully terminated")

if os.path.exists("ot.log"):
    os.remove("ot.log")
```

Agradezco cualquier aporte, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tu mismo hilo tiene el archivo en uso. De acuerdo a la [documentación oficial](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#loguru._logger.Logger.remove), habría que usar remove para liberar el recurso.

```
from loguru import logger
import os

i = logger.add("ot.log")
logger.success("Successfully terminated")
logger.remove(i)

logger.info("No longer logging")
if os.path.exists("ot.log"):
    os.remove("ot.log")
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, creo que hay un error en la primera linea  ```i = logger.logger.add("ot.log")``` seria sin un logger?, ya lo probe asi (sin un  .logger) y me sale lo mismo, y con el logger adicional me aparece que no existe este atributo, alguna sugerencia?